# Error in Conformal Inference Guide Example

Tags: r

I am attempting to run the examples provided in the [Conformal Inference Guide](https://github.com/ryantibs/conformal/blob/master/conformalInference.pdf) using R. However, I encountered an error while executing the code provided in the guide.

Here's the code snippet I'm trying to run:

```
library(glmnet)
library(conformalInference)
library(plyr) 
library(dplyr)

## Lasso: use a fixed sequence of 100 lambda values
# Generate some example training data
set.seed(33)
n = 100; p = 120; s = 10
x = matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
beta = c(rnorm(s),rep(0,p-s))
y = x %*% beta + rnorm(n)
# Generate some example test data
n0 = 50
x0 = matrix(rnorm(n0*p),n0,p)

y0 = x0 %*% beta + rnorm(n0)
# Grab a fixed lambda sequence from one call to glmnet, then
# define lasso training and prediction functions
if (!require("glmnet",quietly=TRUE)) {
  stop("Package glmnet not installed (required for this example)!")
}
out.gnet = glmnet(x,y,nlambda=100,lambda.min.ratio=1e-3)
lambda = out.gnet$lambda
funs = lasso.funs(lambda=lambda)
```

However, I encounter the following error:

```
Error in !is.numeric(lambda) || min(lambda) <= 0 || (order(lambda) !=  : 
  'length = 96' in coercion to 'logical(1)
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!